# Styling the parent list with css

Tags: html, css

For the below list, i want to style the parent list only like ( first parent ) 
i tried to use :

```
  ul < li {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
```

put this doesn't work , how can i do that ?

```
    <ul>
  <li>first parent <!-- style this -->
    <ul>
      <li>second</li>
      <li>second</li>
      <li>second</li>
      <li>second</li>
      <li>second</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>first parent</li> <!-- style this -->
  <li>first parent</li> <!-- style this -->
  <li>first parent</li> <!-- style this -->
  <li>first parent</li> <!-- style this -->
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't target a parent in CSS. You should just add a class to it and use it that way.

```
<li class="highlight">
```

-

```
.highlight {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Or, designate that specific li by it's position in its parent.

```
li:nth-child(5) { /* assuming it's the 5th <li> in that list */
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Let's be clear here, just in case someone is finding this from a
>   search engine: **there are no parent selectors in CSS**, not even in CSS3.

[check this tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/).

Here is the discuss about it: [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, you could use a class.

Or style both like this:

```
ul li { background-color: yellow; }
ul li ul li { background-color: none; }
```

Id probably use a class

Answer (score 0):

you need to apply a class to identify your "first level" like this :

```
<ul class="firstLevel">
  <li>first parent <!-- style this -->
    <ul>
      <li>second</li>
      <li>second</li>
      <li>second</li>
      <li>second</li>
      <li>second</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>first parent</li> <!-- style this -->
  <li>first parent</li> <!-- style this -->
  <li>first parent</li> <!-- style this -->
  <li>first parent</li> <!-- style this -->
</ul>
```

Then apply css :

```
/* ">" means only first level childs "li" will be concerned */
ul.firstLevel > li { 
  background-color: yellow;
}
```